# Error when attempting to create/add data to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I attemp to create/add data to my SQLite database I get a great many errors but do not know why as it looks as tho it should work to me. The code is bellow and ill post the errors below that. Thanks a million in advance for any help.

```
enter code here
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //create an instance of the PlayerDatabase class and pass this context through parameters;
      PlayerDatabase playerProfile = new PlayerDatabase(this);

      try
      {
         //open the database;
         playerProfile.open();
      }//try;
      catch (SQLException e)
      {
         //print description of the error;
         e.printStackTrace();
      }//catch;

      //insert data into the table;
      playerProfile.createInsert("Player", "Connor", "5", "1234");
      //close the database;
      playerProfile.close();
   }//onCreate;
}//class;



public class PlayerDatabase
{
   public static final String KEY_PLAYER = "Player";
   public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
   public static final String KEY_GUESSES = "NumberOfGuesses";
   public static final String KEY_NUMBER= "NumberToGuess";

   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PlayerData.db";
   private static final String DATABASE_MARKSTABLE = "PlayerData";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   //create instance of DbHelper class called ourHelper;
   private DbHelper ourHelper;
   //create a context called ourContext;
   private final Context ourContext;
   //create an instance of SQLiteDatabase called ourDatabase to be the database;
   private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


   //constructor to pass through context;
   public PlayerDatabase(Context c)
   {
      ourContext = c;
   }//constructor;


   //open the database;
   public PlayerDatabase open()throws SQLException
   {
      //finish creating the instance of the DbHelper class;
      ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
      //create database;
      ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this;
   }//open;

   //close the database;
   public void close()
   {
      ourHelper.close();
   }//close;


   //insert data into the database;
   public long createInsert(String player, String name, String guesses,
                        String number)
   {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(KEY_PLAYER, player);
      cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
      cv.put(KEY_GUESSES, guesses);
      cv.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
      return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_MARKSTABLE, null, cv);
   } //createInsert;




   //DbHelper class within PlayerDatabase class;
   private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
   {

      public DbHelper(Context context)
      {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }//DbHelper constructor;


      //when DbHelper is first created it will create this table;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_MARKSTABLE + " (" +
             KEY_PLAYER + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
             KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
             KEY_GUESSES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
             KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
         );
      }//DbHelper onCreate;


      //only used when database is upgraded;
      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_MARKSTABLE);
         onCreate(db);
      }//DbHelper onUpgrade;
    } //class DbHelper;
}//class;
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR REPORT**

```
12-27 13:15:43.549: ERROR/ActivityThread(6572): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cea8d8 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cea8d8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-27 13:15:43.549: ERROR/StrictMode(6572): null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cea8d8 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-27 13:15:43.739: ERROR/ActivityThread(6572): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd08b0 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd08b0 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId12-27 13:24:07.950: ERROR/StrictMode(6572): null
12-27 13:24:10.041: ERROR/ThrottleService(6245): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you're seeing are from the inbuilt email app in Android. It seems to have a leaky `ServiceConnection`, and you're seeing some errors because of that in the LogCat. This is completely unrelated to your app, and you can safely ignore it.

In the future, you can try filtering the logcat using your apps process ID so that only messages from your app are shown, and messages like this which may lead to false positives are hidden.

Comment: @user1985369 That error has been in the email app for as long as I can remember :P You aren't the first person who got confused by it

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of exchange sevices you android emolator is unable to get ID. you should to to settings-> app -> allapps -> and disable exchange services from there.

Hoping the answer of the question.